# EXCEL : Making A Bar Graph With 3 Axis?

Tags: excel, graph, bar-chart

I would like to graph the following data on a 3-axis bar graph in excel. I've uploaded the picture of the data here:

[image: scr1]

I have three gel types for which I did viscosity testing in the lab. I was told by my instructor to make a bar graph containing the each gel's molecular weight on the X axis, Gelation Temperature on the left Y-axis, and the maximum viscosity of each gel on the second right-hand side Y axis. (I've drawn an example of how it should look here:

[image: scr2]

Note that the data on the axis is randomly made up and does not reflect my data).

I've never had to make a 3-axis graph in my life, so after having tried for the past 2 hours, I'm simply stuck.

I would really appreciate your help on how I can proceed on this dilemma. Also, if making such a graph is impossible in bar format, I would love to hear the next best chart type for making this particular graph. Sorry I'm making you click on links, I forgot my previous login information, and I need 10+ rep points to post images). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bar graph isn't really meant to assign a numerical value to the bars themselves, as they are categorical data which has no numerical value.

The primary/secondary y-axis part of your question can be handled in excel. If you remove the molecular weight column, then select your Gel, Temp, and Viscosity columns, then do `insert->2D Column`.

Then, right click a column and choose `"Format Data Series"` then for the `"Plot Series On"` option choose `"Secondary axis"`. This will accomplish everything except spacing the bars apart by weight; for a bar graph it wants to space the bars evenly.

Sorry this does not completely answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I'll have to resort to using another method for graphing all three on the same graph :(